# Error: Cannot Spawn C:\Path To\TortoiseGit\Bin: No such file or directory

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-bash

Trying to do a fetch from origin:

```
git remote update
```

Get the error

```
Error: Cannot Spawn C:\Path To\TortoiseGit\Bin: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
Error: Could not fetch origin
```

Why is this happening? Also is there a fix?

Comment: Do you get the same error with git fetch? For example: git fetch origin

Comment: yes I get the same issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This blog would seem to be the exact same problem that you have:

http://www.techneiq.com/2012/08/error-cannot-spawn-cprogram.html

And this issue on msysgit also points to the same error:

https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=313

Find out what your GIT_SSH environmental variable is pointing to and if that path has a space in it. Maybe reinstalling TortoiseGit would solve it. (Otherwise I can really recommend [GitExtensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) instead)

Comment: Pointing to plink.exe/tortoiseplink.exe explicitly in my environment variables worked, before I was pointing to the files parent folder...

Answer (score 18):

For me the answer was removing the double quotes of "c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe" from the environment variable GIT_SSH.

Comment: This, and removing the spaces in the directory name (e.g. GIT_SSH=C:\Progra~2\PuTTY\plink.exe )

Comment: Removing the double quotes was enough for me, it works even though I have spaces in the directory name.

Comment: My understanding is, that Windows is aware that a path in a environment variables may have spaces and therefor has no need for quotes and always accepts spaces.

Answer (score 10):

Set environment variable `GIT_SSH` to

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PuTTY\plink.exe
```

or

```
%ProgramFiles%\PuTTY\plink.exe
```

Answer (score 8):

I faced this problem when I was required to remove and install the TortoiseGit and Git. Previously both was installed on C:\ but later I installed those on F:. So after re-installing when I tried to pull repositories it was giving me the following error while using from context menu

error: cannot spawn C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoisePlink.exe: No such file or directory

After little bit investigation I went to Settings->Network and update the SSH Client path from C:... to F:... and then it was resolved.

Comment: This is usually the problem in the latest version of TortoiseGit. The environment variables is a poor choice of name as it conflicts with Windows' one for system variables.

Comment: My git was at git_2.17.1 and thus tortoise git was failing your comment is spot on perfect thanks for sharing the fix.

Answer (score 2):

For me, for TortoiseGit>Settings>Network>SSH , I had to set it to just `ssh.exe` instead of the full path to ssh.

Answer (score 0):

You can just find the  copy the directory into the place which the error message has point out.