# Git Extensions "function not implemented"

Tags: windows, git, git-extensions, git-for-windows

I'm trying to use [Git Extensions](https://gitextensions.github.io/) on a new Windows 7 machine. I have done that many times before but never hit this particular issue.

Git Bash is working, I successfully cloned a repository.

But going to Git Extensions, opening the repo, and doing a pull gives me the following error message:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" pull --progress "origin"
error: cannot spawn git: Function not implemented
Done

Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

My setup is very ordinary. The Git Extensions startup checks all pass. (This is similar but not the same problem as the common invalid path issue.)

Do you have any idea what causes this problem?

Comment: which Version of git-extensions do you use?

Comment: Version 2.50.02

Comment: As with the same version of Git-Extensons pull is working for me, it's quiet sure that the problem is on your box and not Git-Extensions as such. Did you check if in the above mentioned path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Cannot Spawn C:\Path To\TortoiseGit\Bin: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139562/error-cannot-spawn-c-path-to-tortoisegit-bin-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Error is 'function not implemented', not 'no such file or directory'.

Comment: If I set "Path to Linux tools (sh)" to be the same as Git Bash (c:\Program Files (x86)\Git), then the bash launched from git-extensions Tools menu will work. However, when I go back to Settings, the path gets cleared out, and clicking OK will cause that same method to fail with 'function not implemented'. Also setting this path does not fix the GUI pull button.

Comment: It seems that you are not the only one. https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1475 Defintively not a GitExtensions problem but more a git one..

Comment: Got the same error with `git clone` using 2.16.2.  The previous version 2.16.1 seems to be ok, and can be downloaded from https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/

Comment: Confirmed! git version 2.16.1.windows.1 is OK, git version 2.16.1.windows.2 is not.

Comment: A new release, *2.16.1 (3)*, is supposed to come out today that fixes this.

Comment: The [2.16.1 (3) release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/) @poke mentioned is out and seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new releases, [Git for Windows 2.16.1(3)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.16.1.windows.3) and [Git for Windows 2.16.1(4)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.16.1.windows.4), fix this regression:

> #### 2.16.1(3) Bug Fixes
>
> - When `http.sslBackend` is not configured (e.g. in portable Git or MinGit), fetch/push operations [no longer crash](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1474).
> - On Windows 7 and older, Git for Windows v2.16.1(2) was no longer able to spawn any processes (e.g. during fetch/clone). This regression [has been fixed](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1475).
> - The Perl upgrade in v2.16.1(2) broke `git send-email`; This [has been fixed](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1480) by updating the Net-SSLeay Perl module.

The mentioned regression in the second bullet point is exactly the error this question is about.

Unfortunately, there was one missing issue about spawning processes which was then fixed in the subsequent fourth release:

> #### 2.16.1(4) Bug Fixes
>
> - When called from TortoiseGit, `git.exe` [can now spawn processes again](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1481).

---

Note that the download on https://git-scm.com/download/win might not have been update *yet*, so you need to download it from [gitforwindows.org](https://gitforwindows.org/) or directly from [the release page on GitHub](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.16.1.windows.4).

Afterwards, you can verify that you indeed running the new version using `git --version` which should report `git version 2.16.1.windows.4`.

Comment: For TortoiseGit users, better use https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.16.1.windows.4 as it works well with TortoiseGit now (another similar regression fixed).

Answer (score 4):

Per Philippe and Jake - bug is filed against GIT 2.16.2, and workaround is to go back to prior version.

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.16.1.windows.1

Answer (score 0):

Running an update on my machine to Git for Windows v2.21.0- just a slightly updated version fixed the issue with my Windows 7 installation at work.
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.21.0.windows.1/Git-2.21.0-32-bit.exe