# Git add . causing Function not implemented error

Tags: git

I'm pretty new to git and have come across this strange error when adding files to this particular project. Whenever I do a `git add .` A string of errors about my `includes` and `lib` folders, several thousand lines long. It does not prevent the add but it's adding a lot of time to my dev cycle.

How can I bypass these errors?

[image: Error]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48601101/2988730

Comment: Have you tried to copy your error message (minus the specific folder name perhaps) into Google?

Comment: Yeah I looked around. I've only really found that article and I have git version 2.20.0

Comment: Any extra stuff installed besides vanilla git?

Comment: Not really. This is a very large Magento repository with many facets, but I do not run locally.

Comment: What OS? w32? [Symlinks problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30616779/7976758)?

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise. 64bit

Comment: [Please do not post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because my repository was on a network drive.

Moving it to a local drive solved the issue... Many hours could have been saved :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I cloned the repo when the core.symlinks option was not enabled, and then I couldn't fix them with `git checkout` or `git restore`.

I fixed it by manually deleting all of them (they appear in the `git status` output as modified) from Explorer (or with the `rm` command), then recreating them with `git checkout path/to/filename` (from a powershell running as administrator).