# Tortoise Git: Getting can not spawn error while performing git push

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Tortoise Git does not allow me to push my code.

```
git.exe push --progress "origin" <<branch_name>>
```

It is throwing below error

```
error: cannot spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPlink.exe: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

Tortoise git does not allow to clone the code as well so I used git bash instead and it worked.

I am not sure, what needs to be corrected for Tortoise GIT as PUSH and Clone commands works well for GIT Bash. Clueless :(

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15139562/6309), check your:

- GIT_SSH environment variable (within Windows): if it has quotes around it, remove those quotes
- `Settings->Network` (within TortoiseGit): update your SSH Client path to the path of `TortoiseGitPlink.exe`, without quotes

As the [OP Gendaful](https://stackoverflow.com/users/515990/gendaful) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55838447/tortoise-git-getting-can-not-spawn-error-while-performing-git-push/55842146?noredirect=1#comment98367956_55842146):

> My problem was on the same lines.
>
> It did not have TortoiseGitPlink.exe path in double quotes, but:
>
> - the tortoise git was installed as TortoiseGit_2.5.2 and
> - the path had the reference as "TortoiseGit"
>
> which was making the `TortoiseGitPlink.exe` unreachable.
>   Corrected the path and it started working.

Comment: My problem was on the same lines. It did not have TortoiseGitPlink.exe path in double quotes, but the tortoise git was installed as TortoiseGit_2.5.2 and the path had the reference as "TortoiseGit" which was making the TortoiseGitPlink.exe unreachable. Corrected the path and it started working. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Gendaful Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.