# while committing changes I got the below error

Tags: git

error: cannot spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe: No such file or directory
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object

Answer (score 0):

This happens, if your PATH has space in it.

Below link has the answer to your question;

[Error: Cannot Spawn C:\Path To\TortoiseGit\Bin: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139562/error-cannot-spawn-c-path-to-tortoisegit-bin-no-such-file-or-directory)